# SVN status..how to use that function

Tags: linux, svn, unix

In linux, how do I check if someone has not yet committed something?

I remember I made changes on a server once..but forgot to commit. Now, I don't know which server I used to make those changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't possible to tell if someone else has uncommitted changes in their working copy, because the status of the working copy of each user isn't sent to the repository.

Answer (score 2):

SVN servers/repositories don't keep track of changes made on clients.  You'd need to locate all the possible places where the client changes might be and check for modifications there.

This is one of the tradeoffs of not having the server keep track of *everything* like Perforce does.  On the other hand, having the server keep track of everything can be a pain at times.

Answer (score 0):

A local working copy is just that, local. The Subversion repository can't know which client has uncommitted changes.

FWIW, you can check a local working copy status using `svn st`

```
svn help st
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell if anyone other than yourself has checked out a revision and made changes which have not been committed.  The only way to find out is to login as each user and execute `svn status` in the appropriate directory.